# Redirect state to otherwise after refresh page

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, oclazyload

I use `oclazyload` to inject modules in my app, and `ui-router` to create states, everything work fine i can move between state `home` or `users` **but** when we change state to `users.list` and press `F5` (refresh) state return to the `otherwise state` *(/application/partials/index.html)*, **what should i do to stay in `users.list` state after refreshing the page?**

**index.html**

```
<div ng-app="app">
    <a ui-sref="/">home</a>
    <a ui-sref="users.list">users</a>

    <div ui-view></div>
    <script src="Scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/ocLazyLoad.js"></script>

    <script src="app.js"></script>
</div>
```

**Main app**

```
var app = angular.module("app", ["ui.router", "oc.lazyLoad"]);

app.config(function ($ocLazyLoadProvider, $stateProvider) {
    $ocLazyLoadProvider.config({
      modules: [{
        name: 'users',
        files: ['/application/modules/users/app.js']
      }]
    }); 

    $stateProvider.state('/', {
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: '/application/partials/index.html'
    });

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
})

app.run(function ($ocLazyLoad) {
    $ocLazyLoad.load("users");
});
```

**application/modules/users/app.js**

```
var app = angular.module("users", []);

app.config(['$stateProvider', function ($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state('users', {
        abstract: true,
        url: '/users',
        template: '<div ui-view="users"></div>'
    });

    $stateProvider.state('users.list', {
        url: '/list',
        module: "users",
        views: {
            "users": {
                parent: "users",
                templateUrl: '/application/modules/users/partials/index.html'
            }
        }
    });
}]);
```

Comment: Did you try defining `url: 'users'` in the abstract state, and define `url: 'users/list'` in `users.list` state? And before pressing F5, what is the exact url in the browser?

Comment: Hi, no need to define them, because we used nested states and adding `users` to url without `/` not work!; before refresh we have `localhost:8080/#!/users/list` after `localhost:8080/#!/`